# How to center something vertically on screen when using UINavigationController on iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

I've got a `UIView` defined in IB within a `UIViewController`, and I have placed completely centered (vertical and horizontal) an activity spinner.  This all looks great, except in practice I use it by pushing the UIViewController on to a `UINavigationController` - hence, it displays "pushed down" my screen 50 pixels or whatever, so my spinner is no longer centered.

How do you address this?  I want the same code to work on all iOS devices. I don't mind adding it programatically - maybe I need to? But I don't know how to make use of screen size vs view size vs nav view size and then end up with "local" coordinate frame for the spinner.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting its `center` property to the same value of the hosting view's one.
So in `viewDidLoad`, do something like :

`myIndicator.center = self.view.center;`

This should make it, but you can also calculate it with few instructions.

Comment: what do you mean by the Hosting View's one?  A view hosted by the UINavigationController?  Can you be exactly specific please?  I did fool with this property but never got the results I wanted (or any results)

Comment: since the `UIActivityIndicatorView` is a `UIView` descendant, it has a `center` property. Try making both properties having the same value (activity view and its hosting view)

Comment: Hi Vince, nope I'm battling issues reverting back to non-beta Xcode (ugh), probably can't try until Thursday night or so.  I still imagine it to be offcenter of my entire screen if it centers based on the UIView of the UIViewController that's been pushed on to the UINavigationController.. I'll experiment